# Django Join Optimization

Tags: sql, django

I'm making a toy Django app to get familiar with the web framework. I'm making a roommate expense tracking site. There is a Roommate model and an Expense model, and a many to many relationship between them -- one roommate can have many expenses, and one expense can be shared among multiple roommates. I want to display all expenses and by each expense, list the roommates who are part of the expense.

The way I'm doing it now is to query for all expenses, then iterate over each expense and query for roommates that are associated. I then return the info in a dictionary and render it using a template. Is there a more efficient way to replicate the functionality below?

```
dct = {}
expenses = Expense.objects.order_by("name")
for exp in expenses:
    dct[exp] = exp.roommates.order_by("first_name")


return render_to_response('expenses/view_expenses.html', {'dct':dct}, context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try something like this:

```
expenses = Expense.objects.order_by("name", "roommates__first_name")
```

An other solution: adding a default ordering field in your Roommate model:

```
ordering = ['first_name']
```

Then in your view, you query only the expenses:

```
expenses = Expense.objects.order_by("name")
```

And in the template you can access your Roommate data like this:

```
{% for roommate in expenses.roommates.all %}
    {{ roommate.first_name }}
{% endfor %}
```